# how to get developer key for Bing Ads API

Tags: java, bing, bing-api

I am trying to create an application using BING ADS API in java , but the demo program needs developer key .

i have account on bing ads ( https://secure.bingads.microsoft.com )

but i am not able to generate any developer key( `devToken="something"` )

can anybody please help with api ??
any tutorial or any suggestion is deeply appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your account is already enabled for API access you can attain this information in the Users tab in adCenter under Accounts and Billing by clicking on "Get API Access Key".

If your account not enabled for API access kindly request access to the API by going to:

http://advertising.microsoft.com/small-business/request-adcenter-api-access

Then set `devToken=#api_key`

There is also a tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh854970.aspx

Comment: i have added the super user , but i am not getting the option to generate the dev token , i have also submitted the form you posted , no progress yet , can you suggest what i might be missing ??